# How to do (unit) testing of Drupal specific JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, testing

For PHP code in custom module, we use SimpleTest. But how do you test the JavaScript code in a module or a theme?

I known about JavaScript testing frameworks like [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) or [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit), but I'm curious to known if and how they are used to test Drupal specific JavaScript code.

Comment: You could also take a look at [fireunit](http://fireunit.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now we don't have any automated testing of the UI. There have been talks about using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and there is even a [proposed session](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/automated-ui-testing-selenium) about it for DrupalCon London, but i don't know of any work that has been done yet.

This could be a nice contribution for Drupal 8.

Comment: I think someone started with that and got some basic selenium tests working. Some details can be found on this site: http://ygerasimov.com/integrating-selenium-to-drupal-simpletest-framework

Comment: We use selenium to test lots of ui things. We use it together with [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (former hudson) and it works fine. Problem is the total runtime of all tests (~60 min) although we do not test nearly every (non-admin) form.

Comment: Selenium is great for front end testing however it isn't 'unit' testing more system testing.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a gsoc project which takles with this problem: http://groups.drupal.org/node/139709

This plan sounds like a good solution